# QLabel click event using Qt?

Tags: qt, signals-slots, qlabel

I'm new in Qt and have a question.

I have `QLabel` and `QLineEdit` objects, and when `QLabel` text is clicked on, I want to set this text in `QLineEdit`.

Also I have read that `QLabel` has not clicked signal.

Can you explain how can I do this and write code for me ?!

Comment: you have to subclass QLabel : look here https://wiki.qt.io/Clickable_QLabel

Comment: I would emit the signal on `mouseReleaseEvent` and not on `mousePressEvent`. The click is not complete until the mouse is released.

Comment: Some random thoughts since I am having a similar problem with a LCD touch screen and tap events... It might be easier to use a QButton rather than a QLabel since the button already knows a click/tap event. Set the button to flat or 2D without a border. Then, handle the button's click/tap event as usual.

Answer (score 8):

Either style another type of QWidget such as a specific QPushButton to look like a QLabel and use its clicked() signal or inherit QLabel yourself and emit your own clicked() signal.

See this example:
https://wiki.qt.io/Clickable_QLabel

If you choose the latter option you can pass the text in the signal. Then connect the necessary signals/slots up between the QLabel and the QLineEdit like so:

```
QObject::connect(&label, SIGNAL(clicked(const QString& text)),
                 &lineEdit, SLOT(setText(const QString& text)));
```

Answer (score 7):

A simple way to accomplish that, without a need for any subclassing, is a signal source that monitors the events on some object and emits relevant signals:

```
// main.cpp - this is a single-file example
#include <QtWidgets>

class MouseButtonSignaler : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT
  bool eventFilter(QObject * obj, QEvent * ev) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE {
    if ((ev->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress
        || ev->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonRelease
        || ev->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonDblClick)
        && obj->isWidgetType())
      emit mouseButtonEvent(static_cast<QWidget*>(obj), 
                            static_cast<QMouseEvent*>(ev));
    return false;
  }
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void mouseButtonEvent(QWidget *, QMouseEvent *);
  MouseButtonSignaler(QObject * parent = 0) : QObject(parent) {}
  void installOn(QWidget * widget) {
    widget->installEventFilter(this);
  }
};
```

The `emit` keyword is an empty macro, Qt defines it as follows:

```
#define emit
```

It is for use by humans as a documentation aid prefix only, the compiler and `moc` ignore it. As a documentation aid, it means: *the following method call is a signal emission*. The signals are simply methods whose implementation is generated for you by `moc` - that's why we have to `#include "main.moc"` below to include all the implementations that `moc` has generated for the object class(es) in this file. There's otherwise nothing special or magical to a signal. In this example, you could look in the build folder for a file called `main.moc` and see the implementation (definition) of `void MouseButtonSignaler::mouseButtonEvent( .. )`.

You can then install such a signaler on any number of widgets, such as a `QLabel`:

```
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  MouseButtonSignaler signaler;
  QWidget w;
  QVBoxLayout layout(&w);
  QLabel label("text");
  QLineEdit edit;
  layout.addWidget(&label);
  layout.addWidget(&edit);
  signaler.installOn(&label);
  QObject::connect(&signaler, &MouseButtonSignaler::mouseButtonEvent, 
    [&label, &edit](QWidget*, QMouseEvent * event) {
    if (event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
      edit.setText(label.text());
  });
  w.show();
  return app.exec();
}

#include "main.moc"
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create one Custom Label class, which will inherit `QLabel`. Then you can use `MouseButtonRelease` event to check clicking of Label and `emit` your custom signal and catch in one `SLOT`.

Your `.h` file will be as below:

```
class YourLabelClass : public QLabel{

signals:
    void myLabelClicked();       // Signal to emit 

public slots:
    void slotLabelClicked();    // Slot which will consume signal 

protected:
    bool event(QEvent *myEvent); // This method will give all kind of events on Label Widget    
};
```

In your `.cpp` file, your constructor will connect signal & slot as below :

```
YourLabelClass :: YourLabelClass(QWidget* parent) : QLabel(parent) {
   connect(this, SIGNAL(myLabelClicked()), this, SLOT(slotLabelClicked()));
}
```

Remaining `event` method and `SLOT` method will be implemented as below:

```
bool YourLabelClass :: event(QEvent *myEvent)  
{
    switch(myEvent->type())
    {        
        case(QEvent :: MouseButtonRelease):   // Identify Mouse press Event
        {
            qDebug() << "Got Mouse Event";
            emit myLabelClicked();
            break;
        }
    }
    return QWidget::event(myEvent);
}

void YourLabelClass  :: slotLabelClicked()   // Implementation of Slot which will consume signal
{
    qDebug() << "Clicked Label";
}
```

For Changing a Text on `QLineEdit`, you need to create a Custom Class and share object pointer with custom `QLabel` Class. Please check test code at [this link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B3m9ig6-SoCfbi1nYTZHcE1zNVU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Ok. But where is code , when I clicked on custom created label text, it sets to QLineEdit object ?

Comment: @Nicholas : You need to create QLineEdit object and share that pointer with QLable, anyways I made a quick project. Please check link in answer

Comment: And one question please: why need emit signal, when we can connect using Qt::connect ? What does emit keyword and when to use it ?

Comment: This link will explain you signal and slot : http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

Comment: If you make the `myLabelClicked()` signal pass a `QString` parameter, that can simply be connected to the `setText()` slot of the `QLineEdit`.  No need to pass a pointer.

Comment: Any chance to get an example in Python? The example at https://wiki.qt.io/Clickable_QLabel also uses C++ and I'm having a hard time finding the correct Python implementation.

Comment: @Cirrocumulus I don't think you can subclass C++ class in Python because ther you just have a wrapper library PyQt, can you? event filters or qpushbutton setStyleSheet are the way

Answer (score 1):

In the above example the header needs Q_OBJECT:

class YourLabelClass : public QLabel{

Q_OBJECT

signals:

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).