# Make Qlabel clickable or double clickable in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, mouseevent, qlabel

I am beginner in Qt, now I want to make my label clickable, I have searched so much online, but no one gives my a real example of how they made it. So can someone teach me step by step? Now my basic thinking is creating a new .c file and new .h file respectively and then include them into my mainwindow.c and then connect it with the existing label in ui form. These are what I was trying to do, but can not make it. Hope someone can teach and better put the step picture in the command, thanks.
Here is the clicklabel.h code:

```
#ifndef CLICKEDLABEL_H
#define CLICKEDLABEL_H

#include <QWidget>
#include <QLabel>

class ClickedLabel : public QLabel
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    ClickedLabel(QWidget *parent=0): QLabel(parent){}
    ~ClickedLabel() {}
signals:
    void clicked(ClickedLabel* click); 
protected:
    void mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent*); 
};

#endif // CLICKEDLABEL_H
```

This the clicklabel.c code:

```
#include "clicklabel.h"
void ClickedLabel::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *)
{
    emit clicked(this); 
}
```

These are what I added into my mainwindow.c( the name of the label is click_test):

```
void data_labeling::on_label_clicked()
{
    QString path="/home/j/Pictures/images.jpeg";
    QPixmap cat(path);
    connect(ui->click_test, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, 
SLOT(on_label_clicked()));
    ui->click_test->setPixmap(cat);
    ui->click_test->resize(cat.width(),cat.height());

}
```

Of course I have promoted it to clicklabel.h and also I have added void on_label_click() to my mainwindow.h under private slots, but nothing happened.

Comment: In one of my answers I made a [derived `QLabel` with `mousePressEvent()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44451423/7478597). Update: It is quite similar like suggested by @zapredelom.

Comment: Also see [QLabel click event using Qt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32018941/608639)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Create a new class derived from `QLabel`, reimplement `mousePressEvent` to emit custom `pressed()` signal (or any other functionality you need)

If you need to use your clickable label in ui files, follow these steps:

1. Add `QLabel` to the form
2. Right-click on added label and select `Promote to...`
3. Enter your clickable label class name and its header file name
4. Press add, than select your label in the tree and select `promote`

[image]

[image]

Now you can use your subclassed label (this tutorial actually works for any subclassed widget) as any QWidget using `ui->`

Comment: thanks! but for the final step, if I want to my existing label clickable, I need writr  ui->label in my new clickablelabel.cpp ? And what should I do? so sorry for asking in detail, I am really a beginner in Qt

Comment: In clickablelabel.cpp you have the code of your clickable label class, it has nothing to do with the existing ordinary `QLabel`. You have existing label somewhere (I suppose in your main window), that's where you need to promote label (if it's created in designer) or change `QLabel` to `ClickableLabel` if it's created dynamically in the code (in this case don't forget to include clickablelabel.h in main window header file)

Comment: yup, the existing Qlabel is in my ui form and in my mainwindow, but how  to make it work? For example if i want to show a second dialog bu clicking the label? where and how do I write the code ? I only don't know the structure of writing the code

Comment: You should implement a function and connect it to the cickable label signal `pressed` (or `clicked` or whatever you've called it). Creating dialog should probably be implemented in the main window class

Comment: OK I think I got it, tomorrow I try it, thanks. If worked, I will accept you answer

Comment: Sorry, I failed again, can you just give me a whole example of it? The example include all the code like the new .c file and new .h file and make the label cilckable, after I click the label, I can receive a information box. Can you teach me? So sorry I am so stupid to make it.

Comment: OMG! I forgot to search on github! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I've just made this project for you

Comment: Thanks!  Thanks! thanks! The important thing must be said 3 times!

Comment: You can upvote the answer as an addition to your thanks

Comment: How will the promotion know how to construct the custom widget?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb you have the header file with the custom constructor defined

Comment: @bearded but how will the promotion know what arguments to pass?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `QPushButton` instead, but if you desperately need `QLabel`, you can do this:

> clickable.h

```
class Clickable :public QLabel
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    signals:
        void clicked();
    public:
        void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event);
    
        using QLabel::QLabel;
    };
```

> clickable.cpp

```
void Clickable::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent* event)
{
    emit clicked();
}
```

UPDATE:
This implementation I used in my source code. I can't paste complete code, but here is the part where I used it.

> source.h

```
...
private: 
    QLabel* label1;
    QLabel* label2;
...
```

> source.cpp

```
...
label1 = new Clickable("label1 text", this);
label2 = new Clickable("label2 text", this);
...
connect(label1 , SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(label1clicked()));
connect(label2 , SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(label1clicked()));
...
```

Comment: yes correct and after did this, how can I make my existing label clickable? Do I need promote my existing label or connect it to the class?

Comment: Just change the type in your source  from qlabel to Clickable

Comment: you can't connect label to anything, you just can connect signals

Comment: Do you have any complete example? I don't understand it

Comment: @jycjo i've updated answer, with some part of code. unfortunately i can't add all my code there. I hope this will help

Comment: @zapredelom It is ok, thanks a lot but I also a bit confused. Have you seen my updated code above? If I want to the click_test label show the cat image after I click the label, where I wrote wrong? no error shown after I build

Comment: as i see you connected the signal to on_label_clicked in same function , am I right ? if yes, thats the one problem. You need to setup signal/slot connections before the firts signal was emitthed( mostly on clickable label creation)